Jest testing "Cannot access 'mockDb' before initialization"
import { getDocument, saveDocument } from "./request";

import { getDocument, saveDocument } from "./request";

const mockDb = {
    get: jest.fn(),
    insert: jest.fn(),
};

jest.mock("nano", () => () => ({
    db: {
        use: () => mockDb,
    },
}));

describe("Database operations", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });
    test("should get document successfully", async () => {
        const docId = "test-doc";
        const mockDocument = { _id: docId, name: "test" };
        mockDb.get.mockResolvedValue(mockDocument);
        const result = await getDocument(docId);
        expect(result).toEqual(mockDocument);
        expect(mockDb.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(docId);
    });
});

I'm using NPM nano and using Jest to test my code, I ran the test then it log Cannot access 'mockDb' before initialization. I found some people said use CommonJS, but I want to import using ES6. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Jest module mocks are hoisted so it's most likely a problem with use: () => mockDb. See https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter
